# Need to get error and id in the print statement in oracle sql query

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql

I need a query to print some 4-5 errors in the if condition with id. need to check every error with its occurrence when it occurs 5 times then need to check id. if the same id for the error then need to print the error and associated id.

```
select id from table1  where
data like '% System is down%'
and date>= '05-SEP-15 07.55.00.000000000 PM' and date<= '05-SEP-15 07.59.00.000000000 PM'  
having count(id)>=2 group by id;
```

I need to write this in if statement. If "system down" occurs 5 time with same id "1" then it needs to print as system down with id:1.
else communication error occurs with id 1 the it needs to print as "Communication error with id : 1" like this.

Comment: You filtered out id with 1 twith `having count(id) >=2` guess you want to print communication error with id 2 times? You want exactly 5 times or . >=5 for system down?

Comment: I want to print the id which occurs 5 times with the 'system down' text.

Answer (score 0):

Confused with your requirements but you can adjust the values to get your required results

```
     SELECT DISTINCT id,
                    CASE
                        WHEN count(*) over(PARTITION BY id) >=5 THEN 'System Down'
                        WHEN count(*) over(PARTITION BY id) < 5 THEN 'Communication Error'
                    END AS status
    FROM table1
    WHERE DATA LIKE '% System is down%'
      AND date>= '05-SEP-15 07.55.00.000000000 PM'
      AND date<= '05-SEP-15 07.59.00.000000000 PM'

or


    SELECT id,
           CASE
               WHEN cnt>=5 THEN 'System Down'
               ELSE
               WHEN cnt < 5 THEN 'Communication error'
           END status
    FROM
      (SELECT id,
              count(id) cnt
       FROM table1
       WHERE DATA LIKE '% System is down%'
         AND date>= '05-SEP-15 07.55.00.000000000 PM'
         AND date<= '05-SEP-15 07.59.00.000000000 PM'
       HAVING count(id)>=2
       GROUP BY id)
```

P.S:-Not sure about 1 times but if you want exactly one occurrence  need to comment out having clause(in second method) and set second in case clause to `=1`

Edit :- you can remove second when clause  just use `case when >=5 then 'system down' else 'communication error'`

Comment: 1 st part is working for me. but, i need to add few more errors  "Timeout", "Invalid response". how can i check the condition for those erros like system down ?

Comment: Add additional conditions in `case` clause  based on your requirements or add test case with sample data and expected results

Comment: I don't know how to set condition or test case. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: You're not clear with your requirements and moving goal posts,unless you cannot create a test case with a sample data and desired out put no one can help you.